# How to use DELIMITER in mariadb using the .NET MySql connector?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.12 and connecting using the .NET MySQL connector. The following trigger works fine in MySQL Workbench:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_last_modified
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE miscdataWithDate JSON;
    IF JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(NEW.miscdata, 'all', '$.v1.lastModified2') THEN
        SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_REPLACE(NEW.miscdata, '$.v1.lastModified2', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
    ELSE
        SET miscdataWithDate = JSON_SET('{"v1": {}}', '$.v1.lastModified2', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
        SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_MERGE(NEW.miscdata, miscdataWithDate);
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

To run the command from C#/.NET, I used the following. I tried it with and without the final semicolon, in case the library is adding a semicolon:

```
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"CREATE TRIGGER update_last_modified
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE miscdataWithDate JSON;
        IF JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(NEW.miscdata, 'all', '$.v1.lastModified') THEN
            SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_REPLACE(NEW.miscdata, '$.v1.lastModified', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
        ELSE
            SET miscdataWithDate = JSON_SET('{""v1"": {}}', '$.v1.lastModified', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
            SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_MERGE(NEW.miscdata, miscdataWithDate);
        END IF;
    END; //
    DELIMITER ;", connection))
{
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

When the trigger is defined (not called), the error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//
    DELIMITER' at line 1) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//
    DELIMITER' at line 1
```

If I simplify the query so it doesn't need `DELIMITER` set, it works. But even a very simple trigger with a custom delimiter fails.

Answer (score 1):

When searching for how other people have successfully used delimiters with MySQL/MariaDB from .NET, I found the following article: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html

The example given uses `MySqlScript` instead of `MySqlCommand`, and so I believe that `MySqlCommand` simply doesn't support delimiters. Here is the updated code, which works fine:

```
MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(connection, @"CREATE TRIGGER update_last_modified
    BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE miscdataWithDate JSON;
        IF JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(NEW.miscdata, 'all', '$.v1.lastModified') THEN
            SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_REPLACE(NEW.miscdata, '$.v1.lastModified', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
        ELSE
            SET miscdataWithDate = JSON_SET('{""v1"": {}}', '$.v1.lastModified', UTC_TIMESTAMP());
            SET NEW.miscdata = JSON_MERGE(NEW.miscdata, miscdataWithDate);
        END IF;
    END; //");
script.Delimiter = "//";
await script.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you get rid of the `//` also?

Comment: @RickJames If this script had more than one statement, `//` would be needed between statements. And I believe the delimiter is optional at the end, so IMO it's clearer to keep it at the end of each statement.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to construct a script instead of simply executing the SQL, statement by statement.

Comment: @RickJames You're correct. In my case, this is a non-issue. However, I imagine there are cases where logic is supplied as a .sql file and procedures can't easily be changed. An edge case for sure, but probably important to someone. Moreover, `MySqlScript` allows an easier translation between code and another debugging environment, reducing bugs from reformatting.